# Single VBO and multiple IBOs

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

I have a problem with rendering multiple objects from one vertex buffer.
I have a VBO containing all vertices and multiple IBOs.
My idea was to create n VAOs for n IBOs and bind for each of this VAOs the VBO and one of the IBOs. Dont realy know how to fix this.

```
// all indices
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> allIndices;

// gen buffers for ibos
glGenBuffers(allIndices.size(),ibos);
// gen vaos
glGenVertexArray(allIndices.size(),vaos);

// vbo for vertices
glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...);

// bind VAOn + IBOn + VBO
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < allIndices.size(); x++) {
  glBindVertexArray(vao[x]);

  // bind current ibo
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,ibo[x]);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,...);

  // 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
  // how to bind this buffer to the vao without uploading the data once more?

  glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

My second idea was to concatinate all indices and call them with glDrawRangeElements()

Comment: "*how to bind this buffer to the vao without uploading the data once more?*" You never attached this buffer to the VAO to begin with. Uploading data to a buffer has *nothing* to do with using that buffer for vertex data (other than that you would be passing vertex data to it).

Answer (score 0):

You never attached your VBO to any VAO you use. Each vao must have both buffers attached. However, there's a bit of confusion of how VBO and IBO attached to the VAO (and pipeline if you don't use VAO).

The difference is that when you use `glBindBuffer` with IBO (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target) it does what it means - sets the buffer as index buffer into the pipeline or VAO. However, if you use `glBindBuffer` with VBO (`ARRAY_BUFFER` target) it only sets sort of internal variable and indicates that next commands related to VBO will use that buffer.
Actual binding happens when you call `glVertexAttribPointer`, it implicitly uses last bound VBO.

Keep in mind, that with your approach you should have correct indexes in your IBO which adjusted respectively or use `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` function with correct offset (in case you use original mesh indexes) or use correct offset into vertex data for each VAO you create.

In general you should minimize state changes and having many IBOs or VAOs won't help you with this. It's better to have as much as possible data in one big vertex/index array and use `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` function to render different "parts" of your big buffers.